# PHPUnit class TestCase not found

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I am working on creating a PHP library and want to start writing tests. I am getting an error `Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found`.

My project structure is: in my main directory I have composer.json, a src/ directory with all my classes, a tests/ directory with unit/ and acceptance/ subdirectories. The tests I am trying to run are in the the unit/ directory. I am using the command line interface to run the test so the error happens when running `phpunit tests/unit/testMyClass.php`

testMyClass.php looks like:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyClassTest extends TestCase {
    public function testCreateMyClass() {
        // Tests are written here
    }
}
?>
```

My composer.json is:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*"
    }
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run `composer install`? Does your testMyClass.php file is in the same directory of your vendor directory (where you also run the `composer install`)?

Comment: The class in question doesn't follow the namespaces that you're trying to call it from. Try `use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as TestCase;` if you want to, otherwise just extend the full class name.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by extending my test class from the **PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase** class instead of using the **namespace** **PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase**. After rebuilding your project-structure it worked fine for me.

### tests/unit/testMyClass.php

```
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';

class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
     public function testCreateMyClass() {
        // Tests are written here
     }
}
?>
```

### composer.json

```
{
   "name": "root/project",
   "authors": [
      {
           "name": "watzerm",
           "email": "some.email@provider.at"
      }
   ],
   "require": {
       "phpunit/phpunit": "5.4.*"
   },
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "src/"
       ]
   }
}
```

### Result

```
$./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/unit/testMyClass.php

PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.

Time: 252 ms, Memory: 2.25MB

OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

Please let me know if this worked out for you too!

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem with newer version of PHPUnit:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.0.phar
php phpunit-6.0.phar -c app/
```

Output:

```
PHPUnit 6.0.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 486 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

OK (2 tests, 3 assertions)
```

This is working on Symfony 2.8 LTS and PHPunit 6.0 github repo - https://github.com/nikola-bodrozic/PHPUnit-Symfony28

Comment: But this version only runs on PHP7+. The op didn't mention what version he uses though.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the "phpunit.xml" file exists in the project root. In this file there must be a "phpunit" tag with a "bootstrap = "vendor / autoload.php" attribute.
Something like :

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     colors="true">
```

In my case it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with:

```
extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
```

Comment: "php bin/phpunit" will give you info as  "PHPUnit 9.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.... "

Answer (score -1):

You need to run `php bin/phpunit` at root of project, it will download all needed classes and PhpStorm error should gone